# API url is being GET as document and not XHR

Tags: magento-1.9, api, ajax

Currently have a controller with below as the index action.

```
public function indexAction()
{

     $collection = json_encode(Mage::getModel('frequent/question')->getCollection()->getData());

     $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('content-type', 'application/json', true);

     $this->getResponse()->setBody($collection);

}
```

However when I try to get the json data on the request url its not being processed as an XHR request but as a document request. Please see attached image.
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function indexAction()
    {

        $collection = json_encode(Mage::getModel('frequent/question')->getCollection()->getData());

        $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('content-type', 'application/json', true);

        $this->getResponse()->appendBody($collection);


    }
```

The answer was actually provided by Amit Bera, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `toArray($arrRequiredFields = array())` for getting data in array format  from  a collection

**Remove** the `getData();`

Let try this,

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('frequent/question')->getCollection()->toArray();
  $JsonData=Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($collection);
 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
 $this->getResponse()->setBody($JsonData);

}
```

Comment: Hey, hasn't worked still as a document request rather than xhr?

Comment: try this:` $this->getResponse()->appendBody($JsonData);` instead  of  `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
 $this->getResponse()->setBody($JsonData)`

Comment: Still nothing, so wierd, worked perfectly offline outputting the json using echo. But echo created an infinite loop online, and nothing else has been close to working. hmmmmmm

Comment: Hey, i've got it working thanks for your help, here is the solution see additional answer. if you want to update your answer to this solution i've put in place please do so and ill mark it as the correct answer.